# Multiple "copy to clipboard" button for multiple texts using ng-clip AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs

I tried this [example](http://plnkr.co/xwV5Yn):

```
<a href='http://plnkr.co/xwV5Yn'>http://plnkr.co/xwV5Yn</a>
```

but it works  only for the first element irrespective of the copy button on which you click.

Answer (score 0):

It works ...
Now you can check here (http://plnkr.co/edit/SooWkk?p=preview)

```
 var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ngClipboard"]);

  myapp.config(['ngClipProvider', function(ngClipProvider) {
    ngClipProvider.setPath("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/2.1.6/ZeroClipboard.swf");
  }]);

  myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.fallback = function(copy) {
      window.prompt('Press cmd+c to copy the text below.', copy);
    };

    $scope.showMessage = function() {
      console.log("clip-click works!");
    };
  });
```